# How to extract necessary content from file in python?

Tags: python, file, file-read

I have a private key file (private.key) with content in the following format

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am reading the file as follows:

```
pk = open( 'private.key', 'rb' ).read()
```

How do I eliminate the first line and last line and extract just the private key content into the variable pk?

Expecting something similar in python to

```
egrep -v "PRIVATE KEY" private.key | tr -d "\n\r"
```

Comment: there is no need for binary read mode `'b'` as your key is base64 encoded. this module will come in handy after you have solved your problem above: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/base64.html#module-base64 . and also this may help: https://python-gnupg.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gnupg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
pk = open( 'file.txt', 'r' ).readlines() #or 'rb' if there's a need

if len(pk) > 2:
    for line in pk[1:-1]:
        print line,
        #or do anything you like to do with line
```

to avoid processing of first and last line in the lines list

Comment: Why are you using `rb` mode?

Comment: because author is using it - of course it can be just r

Comment: why -2 on this? I've checked it and it works - why is it not good way to do it? The fact is that I haven't pointed out that **readlines** is necessary instead of **read** int the "first version"

Comment: I've just removed my downvote(however, read a plain text file don't need `b` mode) and upvoted for this :)

Comment: It is true that people should explain their negative points, I hate it when this happens. On the other hand, the code you posted *prints* the lines the user wants to *extract*, maybe for later use.

Comment: @Jblasco And it's sad that SO doesn't send a notify to downvoter if the answer or question has been edited.

Comment: @m.antkowicz  can you explain what pk[1:-1] means?

Comment: @KurinchiMalar Take a look about [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)(scroll down and find the *slice* part).

Comment: pk is a list with lines from file - you can use python's extract operator [:] to get a range of list's items. Now [1:] means - *get all from the #1* one (so ommiting first one since list are enumbered from 0) and [:-1] means  *get all to the last one* so to sum up [1:-1] will extract all but first and last lines

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('private.key', 'r') as f: # use with here, it will auto close the file.
    pk = f.readlines()

pk = pk[1:-1]
```

Now, `pk` is a list that saves the private key by lines.
To print it out you can just use `print()` like this:

```
for i in pk:
    print(pk)
```

---

Or, like `egrep` does:

```
with open('private.key', 'r') as f: # use with here, it will auto close the file.
    pk = f.read()

for i in pk:
    if 'PRIVATE' not in i:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more general solution that allows comments in the file (anything outside of the `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` and `END PRIVATE KEY` guard lines) and also handles multiple private keys in a file (but lets you stop reading as soon as you've found the first one if that's what you want), you can use a very simple state machine algorithm in a generator:

```
def private_keys(file):
    key = []
    inside_guards = False
    for line in file:
        if line == "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----":
            inside_guards = True
            continue
        if line == "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----":
            inside_guards = False
            yield data
            data = []
            continue

        if inside_guards:
            data.append(line)
```

Comment: Well, I think that this is so complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('private.key', 'r') as infile:
    pk = infile.read().split('\n', 1)[1].rsplit('\n', 1)[0]
```

Comment: This does not work. print pk  prints only the first line now. Whereas the requirement is pk should have entire key content except BEGIN and END lines.

Comment: @KurinchiMalar: oops! sorry, forgot an optional argument at the end, there. Check out the edit

Comment: Still there is problem. Now I am getting the desired content + -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: The only way that can happen us I'd there's an empty line at the end of your key file. In that case, change the `1` to a `2` in the additional parameter to `rsplit` and you should be fine